# Animate a ChoiceChips' background color on selector state change

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, android-animation, android-transitions

I'm trying to achieve a choice chip group like shown in the [material documentation](https://material.io/design/components/chips.html#choice-chips):

[Link to Animation Video](https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-design%2Fassets%2F1kmAs_G2pTnVZIlsv3uCAvVZ9-IQCW_2V%2Fchoice-chip-behavior-selecting.mp4)

Currently, I'm just using a selector as a background drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="?attr/colorAccent" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/md_white_1000" />

</selector>
```

Switching those colors given above shall be animated.

If possible, the animation/transition should be compatible to api 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, this is only possible with a custom view.

There's an open issue on MDC to implement animatable backgrounds:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130410732